# Charge density by Gauss divergence theorem when the electric field is dincontinuous

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law

Let's say the electric field across a surface is discontinuous. Now if I want to find the surface charge density which electric field should I use in Gauss divergence theorem?

Answer (score 0):

Discontinuities on the electric field are due to a presence of charge on the surface you're looking at. This can be seen from Gauss's Law itself. If $\mathbf{E}$ has a discontinuity, then $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{E}$ has a [Dirac delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) contribution at the place of discontinuity, which $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{E} = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$ reveals to be just a surface charge density distribution.

With this in mind, notice that if you pick the value of the electric field just below the surface, you won't be taking this surface charge into account. If you take the value just above the surface, you'll take it into account.